# Can Treat Deadly Wounds be used on more than one creature at a time?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, healing

The Heal skill has a use called [Treat Deadly Wounds](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/skills/heal.html#treat-deadly-wounds). It allows the recovery of hit points and takes 1 hour.

Another use of the Heal skill, [Long Term Care](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/skills/heal.html#long-term-care) allows taking care of multiple characters at the same time.

Can Tread Deadly Wounds also be used on multiple characters, or is the one hour spent exclusively on a single person?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no explicit statement in the Treat Deadly Wounds chapter that you can heal multiple persons. And the text just speak of "a creature". So the treatment is single target only.

Specifically, from the PRD:

> When treating deadly wounds, you can restore hit points to a damaged
>   creature.

Comment: The "Takes one hour of work" implies also that you are working on a specific task/person rather than relaxing as you do so.

Comment: @Rob: Admittedly, Long Term Care says "light activity", which is certainly where the difference lies.

Answer (score 4):

There's a BIG difference between emergency triage and the hospital ward.

### Emergency triage

You are concerned with one character who is in the process of dying.  Injury/Illness is compromising their ability to live.  With this level of care, you need to be 100% alert and know as much about the patient at all times.  This is different from getting cut and needing a few stitches.  Treat Deadly Wounds is a character's Aorta is nicked/cut.  They are bleeding out.  You need both hands on the wounded character, your attention to keep them awake/alert (so they don't pass out/go into shock) and frequently you need someone else to pass you stuff as necessary.

### Hospital Ward

This is a less stressful task.  If you have ever seen a doctor make rounds in a hospital/hospital show on TV, this is long-term care.  The doctor has a chart to consult, takes a few minutes with each patient, then moves on.  In a Pathfinder setting, you are likely to take care of a ward of patients, check/change bandages, apply poultices, etc.  You don't need to hurry generally, and when you do, the other patients can wait.

With that in mind, you can either perform Treat Deadly Wounds on one person, or Long Term Care a recovery ward.  The only exception would be if you are doing Long Term Care on a ward of stable patients and a new one comes in needing Treat Deadly Wounds.  Then you administer emergency care to the one patient and then once stabilized count that person as part of the ward when you go back on rounds.

Comment: Good realism based answer.

Comment: "A creature can only benefit from its deadly wounds being treated within 24 hours". Doesn't *too* urgent to me. And in spite of its name, the use could be applied to someone with only one missing Hit Point. Do you recommend at least describing the use as treating something serious, even if it's not mechanically the case?

Answer (score 2):

For deadly wounds, per the other answers, it is implied by the rules as written that it can only work on one creature at a time. Its a life critical situation compared to long term care, which you could in theory take care of more than 1 person if the care wasnt too strenuous but you wouldn't normally be able to take care of yourself with long term care.

However, there are other little abilities tucked away in other classes that most people wont think about.

It is worth noting that normally you can only use Heal skill on one person at a time normally from the wording implied by this oracle revelation. With this particular revelation you could bypass that normal limit.

Healing Hands (Ex): You gain a +4 bonus on Heal checks. You may provide first aid to two people or treat two people for poison as a standard action (make a separate Heal check for each creature). When using the Heal skill to treat wounds from caltrops (and so on), treat deadly wounds, treat poison, treat disease, or treat long-term care, you may treat double the normal number of people you may treat at the same time. You may provide long-term care for yourself.

http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/advanced/baseClasses/oracle.html#_healing-hands

Comment: That's good information, but answers need to be able to answer the question independently. As it is, this answer does not answer the question. Please update it to actually provide an answer - then build on that with the extra information you wish to provide. RPG.SE is not a forum, so merely leaving posts tangentially related is not appropriate use of answers.

Comment: Modified to be separate.

Comment: Much better! :)